# Non-existence of embedded incompressible surfaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, surfaces

I want to prove the following assumption: Let $g,h$ be natural numbers with $g > h$ and let $S_g$ be the closed, orientable surface of genus $g$. Then, there is no (smooth) map $f: S_g \to S_h \times (-1,1)$, *embedding* $S_g$ as an *incompressible* subsurface.

The problem here is that it's not sufficient to look at the fundamental group alone. For any $h$ there exists some $g > h$ and a covering map from $S_g$ to $S_h$. This will induce a smooth map $f: S_g \to S_h \times (-1,1)$ which will provide an injection on fundamental groups. Clearly, however, this $f$ is not embedding.

Similarily, one can easily also construct an embedding on $S_g$ into $S_h \times (-1,1)$, but such a map will not be incompressible.

I tried to argue by contradiction, and came up with the following idea: Suppose there existed an incompressible embedding $f: S_g \to S_h \times (-1,1)$. This would induce a map $f_*: H_1(S_g) \to H_1(S_h)$ which must have non-trivial kernel, since $g > h$. As such, one can find an essential simple closed curve $\gamma \subset S_g$ such that it's *embedded* counterpart $f(\gamma)$ is *null-homologous* in $S_g \times (-1,1)$. Now, somehow, the fact that $f$ is an embedding must imply that $f(\gamma)$ is already *null-homotopic*. How can we show this ?

Comment: This question is answered over in MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131978/is-there-a-way-to-classify-incompressible-surfaces-in-sigma-times-0-1

Comment: Wow. This has turned out far more complex than I would have imagined. Thanks!

Comment: The result that every incompressible surface is isotopic to one that's either vertical or horizontal is true for any Seifert fibered space IIRC. This should be proved in Hatcher's 3-mfds book.

Comment: Fantastic. This is closer to the level of my knowledge on 3-manifolds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch (let me know if you want to see more details on any of these items) of a direct proof which does not require hard classification results which appear in the links, it inly requires differential topology which you can find the the book of Guillemin and Pollack:

1. Each nonempty connected closed subsurface $S\subset M= int(S_h\times [-1,1])$ separates the manifold $M$ in two components.
2. If $S$ does not separate the boundary components of $N=S_h\times [-1,1]$ then $S$ represents the trivial homology class of  $N$, which implies that the inclusion map $S\to N$ cannot be homotopic to a covering map $S\to S_h$, in particular, $S$ cannot be incompressible.
3. Thus, $S$ separates the boundary components. Then the algebraic intersection number between $S$ and any arc $a$ of the form $x\times [-1,1]$ is $\pm 1$ (depending on the orientation). Now, compute the same algebraic intersection number for $a$ and a degree $d$ covering map $S_g\to S_h$. You get $\pm d$. Therefore, since the algebraic intersection number is  homotopy invariant for maps of closed surfaces in to $N$, it follows that $d= \pm 1$.
4. Now, use Euler characteristic to check that for each covering map $S_g\to S_h$ the degree is $\pm 1$ iff $g=h$ and the covering is trivial.

To conclude: $g=h$ for each incompressible surface.

Comment: The only thing that is not clear to me is point 3. I am familiar with intersection pairings for *closed* manifolds. Using Poincaré-duality, it assigns to two homology classes of complementary dimension an integer. If those classes can be represented by compact submanifolds, this will give us precisely the minimal transversal intersection number of those manifolds.

Comment: I am guessing that the algebraic intersection number is defined in a similiar fashion, but using lefschetz-duality instead, since the ambient manifold has boundary. I am not sure how you can directly see that this has to be $\pm 1$. On second thought, I think I can also see this. How can I see that an incompressible embedding is homotopic to a covering map ? Is it because my ambient manifold is irreducible ?

Comment: @Berni Waterman: to see that an inclusion map is homotopic to a covering map you use the face that it induces a monomorphism of fundamental groups and then the basic covering theory: Correspondence between covering maps and subgroups of the fundamental group. Lastly you use Whitehead' theorem to show that maps of surfaces are  homotopic iff they induce the same monomorphism of fundamental groups.

Comment: I am not still not so sure about this. It seems to me we would like to say that a map $f:S_g \to S_h$ that is injective on fundamental groups has the homotopy type of a covering map. But why is this so ? Two maps that induce the same map on all homotopy groups do not necessarily have the same homotopy type in general. What is so special about surfaces ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman: The fact that surfaces are aspherical makes them special, just use Whitehead's theorem as I mentioned above.

Comment: It is not immediatley obvious to me how you would apply Whiteheads theorem. You have to construct a map between two cw complexes that induces an isomorphism between all homotopy groups. Applying whitehead should then somehow result in a homotopy between the two maps.

Comment: @BerniWaterman: You already have the maps: One is the inclusion map $S\to N$. The second is the covering map $S\to S_h\subset N$ associated with the monomorphism of fundamental groups $\phi: \pi_1(S)\to \pi_1(S_h)$. Given this monomorphism, there is a covering $p: S'\to S_h$ such that the image of  $p_*: \pi_1(S')\to \pi_1(S_h)$ i the same as the image of $\phi$. The surface $S'$ is homeomorphic to $S$ since surfaces are determined by their fundamental groups (and an isomorphism of their fundamental groups is always induced by such a homeomorphism - Nielsen's theorem).

Comment: Now identify $S$ and $S'$ via this homeomorphism and take the composition $S\to S'\to S_h$. This is your covering map which induces the monomorphism $\phi$ of fundamental groups. Incidentally, Whitehead can be also used to *construct* maps between CW complexes: Suppose that $X, Y$ are aspherical CW complexes and $\phi: \pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(Y)$ is a homomorphism. Then there exists a continuous map $f: X\to Y$ which induces $\phi$. A proof should be in Hatcher: You define $f$ by induction on skeleta.

Comment: Ahh, I think I got it. If $G: = \pi_1(S_h \times [-1,1])$, we have that $S_h \times [-1,1]$ is a $K(G,1)$. Therefore, there is a natural bijection between the set of homotopy classes of maps between $S_g$ and $S_h \times [-1,1]$ and $H^1(S_g;G)$. Along with what you've already said, this should solve my problems. Thanks!

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Right.

Comment: Call me mistaken, but we didnt really use Whitehead here anywhere, did we ?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to me that you need any major Theorem to prove that the fundamental groups of two distinct closed surfaces cannot be abstractly isomorphic. This already follows for example because they have different abelianizations.

Comment: You need this to argue that the given isomorphism of fundamental groups is induced by a homotopy-equivalence (actually, it is induced by a homeomorphism, but that it a harder theorem). Whitehead was used to argue that the two maps $S'\to S_h$ are homotopic, which is used to show that they induce the same map of $H_2$'s.